# Typing a component map resolver Component for generic use

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, polymorphism

I am working on a project where in the backend it is possible to model dynamic content that is afterwards rendered as Components in the frontend.

It works for most part, except when working with models where the dynamic content is an array of union types that should be then resolved to components.

---

It's easy to do in plain JavaScript as there are no worries, but I am looking to statically type the component mapper.

My goal is to create a mapper such that it would work with this syntax and infer the type names (from keys) and props (from values) while preventing values other than `ComponentType`:

```js
// PageComponentMapper.ts
import componentMapperFactory from './componentMapperFactory'

import Hero from './Hero'
import InstagramFeed from './InstagramFeed'
import FrameBuilder from './FrameBuilder'

export default componentMapperFactory({ 
  Hero, 
  InstagramFeed, 
  FrameBuilder 
})
```

**With usage:**

```js
import { ComponentProps } from 'react'
import PageComponentMapper from './PageComponentMapper'

type PageComponentMapperProps = ComponentProps<typeof PageComponentMapper>
type PageContentItem = 
  PageComponentMapperProps['props'] & 
  { key: string } & 
  { type: PageComponentMapperProps['type'] }
```

**Producing:**

```js
type PageComponentMapperProps = {
  props: HeroProps | InstagramFeedProps | FrameBuilderProps,
  type: "Hero" | "InstagramFeed" | "FrameBuilder"
}
```

**How far I've got:** https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-star-6tqzz

**With this component mapper implementation:**

```js
import { createElement, ComponentType } from "react";

interface ComponentResolverProps<
  ResolvableComponentTypeNames,
  ResolvableComponentPropTypes extends {}
> {
  type: ResolvableComponentTypeNames;
  props: ResolvableComponentPropTypes;
}

// How to infer type names and prop types from map?
export default function componentMapperFactory<
  AvailableComponentTypeNames extends string,
  AvailableComponentPropTypes
>(
  map: {
    [K in AvailableComponentTypeNames]: ComponentType<
      AvailableComponentPropTypes
    >
  }
) {
  return function resolveComponentFromMap({
    type,
    props
  }: ComponentResolverProps<
    AvailableComponentTypeNames,
    AvailableComponentPropTypes
  >) {
    const component = map[type];

    if (!component) {
      return null;
    }

    return createElement(component, props);
  };
}
```

Previously, I actually didn't provide type names and defaulted to string, which did not help me to discern typenames.

---

I have also hacked around with:

```js
export default function componentMapperFactory<
  C extends { [key: string]: ComponentType }
>(
  map: {
    [N in keyof C]: C[N] extends ComponentType<infer P>
      ? (P extends unknown ? ComponentType<{}> : C[N])
      : never
  }
) {
  return function resolveComponentFromMap({
    type,
    props
  }: {
    type: keyof C;
    props: ComponentProps<C["string"]>;
  }) {
    const component = map[type];

    if (!component) {
      return null;
    }

    return createElement(component, props);
  };
}
```

But this loses prop types, I have no idea why and also it seems crazy complicated syntax wise.

CodeSandbox of this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hill-i5cbr

---

So, to sum it up: how do I transform the `componentMapperFactory` so that I can use it without explicit type arguments:

```
export default componentMapperFactory({ 
  Hero, 
  InstagramFeed, 
  FrameBuilder 
})
```

And get these types as result for `ComponentProps<typeof PageComponentMapper>`?

```
type PageComponentMapperProps = {
  props: HeroProps | InstagramFeedProps | FrameBuilderProps,
  type: "Hero" | "InstagramFeed" | "FrameBuilder"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to define all component types and also validate the props based on the component type. All you need is to define a map of all components, and from that map extract 2 types:

1. the type of possible components: which is basically the map keys
2. the type of the component props for a given component: which is the tricky part, because props which are valid for a 'Hero' component may be invalid for an 'InstagramFeed' component. The way to express this is to use a generic type based on the component type, that will return the right props type.

`PageComponentMapper.ts`

```js
import Hero from "./Hero";
import FrameBuilder from "./FrameBuilder";
import InstagramFeed from "./InstagramFeed";
import componentMapperFactory from "./componentMapperFactory";

export default componentMapperFactory({
  Hero,
  FrameBuilder,
  InstagramFeed
});
```

`componentMapperFactory.ts`

```js
import { createElement } from "react";

interface MapType {
  // this is required to make Parameters<T[K]> work
  [key: string]: (...args: any) => any;
}

export default function componentMapperFactory<T extends MapType>(
  contentTypeMap: T
) {
  // 1. K can be any key from the map
  return function<K extends keyof T>({
    type,
    props
  }: {
    type: K;
    // 2. get the component function with key 'K', use the type of its 1st parameter for props
    props: Parameters<T[K]>[0];
  }) {
    const Component = contentTypeMap[type];
    if (!Component) {
      return null;
    }
    return createElement(Component, props);
  };
}
```

for more info check TS docs for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst)

Comment: Hmm, but this doesn't follow the requested syntax, that everything should get resolved inside the `componentMapper`, such that I can call it as: `const PageComponentMapper = componentMapper({ Hero, FrameBuilder, InstagramFeed })` and don't have to specify #1 and #2 beforehand.

Comment: It's the first code block in question that is the Holy Grail.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why block #1 & #2 are a problem, Can you explain that? Can you maybe just export the `ContentTypeMap` and have the rest in another file?

Comment: It's not that the blocks pose a problem. The solutions I came up with myself are already in production and have "no problems" to them as well. It's just that they're tedious to setup and I want to have a cleaner syntax, to make the mapper much more generic and easier to use... to have better DX. In React world everything is a Component, so, all I want to do is think in Components, same as my fellow team members do and so on.

Comment: Ha, yeah, that's it - thanks! Damn TypeScript! Transforming `any` to actual type... didn't occur to me.

Comment: It's inferring the generic type based on the function invocation 

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this, let me know if this is going the wrong direction.

I wrote a Typescript type definitions generator for Contentful a while back, which creates an interface and implementation for each Contentful content-type based on a JSON file which represents the space.  [You can see it here](https://github.com/watermarkchurch/ts-generators/tree/master/packages/contentful-ts-generator).

The approach I took to turn an Interface into an Implementation was to generate a "TypeDirectory" interface.  Using this interface I could reference various fields of the type directory based on a common key.

```
export interface TypeDirectory {
  'campus': C.ICampus;
  'codeButton': C.ICodeButton;
  'card': C.ICard;
  'campus-page': C.ICampusPage;
  'dropdownMenu': C.IDropdownMenu;
  'faq': C.IFaq;
  ...
}

export interface ClassDirectory {
  'campus': C.Campus;
  'codeButton': C.CodeButton;
  'card': C.Card;
  'campus-page': C.CampusPage;
  'dropdownMenu': C.DropdownMenu;
  'faq': C.Faq;
  ...
}

/** Wraps a raw JSON object representing a Contentful entry with the Class implementation appropriate for that type. */
export function wrap<CT extends keyof TypeDirectory>(entry: TypeDirectory[CT]): ClassDirectory[CT] {
  const id = entry.sys.contentType.sys.id
  switch (id) {
    case 'campus':
      return new C.Campus(entry)
    case 'codeButton':
      return new C.CodeButton(entry)
    case 'card':
      return new C.Card(entry)
    ...
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown content type:' + id)
}
```

I've used this approach in other places as well, where I need to extract properties from a union type.  So you could use a Directory type similar to this:

```
interface TypeDirectory {
    "Hero": { props: HeroProps, impl: Hero },
    "InstagramFeed": { props: InstagramFeedProps, impl: InstagramFeed }
}

function componentMapperFactory<K extends keyof TypeDirectory>(key: K): (props: TypeDirectory[K]['props']) => TypeDirectory[K]['impl'] {
    return function (props: any) {
        // React.createElement...
    } as any
}

const heroFactory = componentMapperFactory('Hero')
const feedFactory = componentMapperFactory('InstagramFeed')

type AnyTypeKey = keyof TypeDirectory
const whateverKey: AnyTypeKey = '...' as any // get from API
const whateverProps: TypeDirectory[AnyTypeKey]['props'] = JSON.parse('' /* get from API */)
const whateverFactory = componentMapperFactory<AnyTypeKey>(whateverKey)
const whateverType: TypeDirectory[AnyTypeKey]['impl'] = whateverFactory(whateverProps)
```

[image: The resulting Typescript inferred types]
[image: whateverType inferred type]

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=72&pln=4&pc=46#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAKgTwA7QCKizTKQD2sWaA3sGvWgEQAScZjAXDWjrGTgGcurPgAU+ggDRpQAWxwAbYWzQBfSXQaMAkuAGREAc1iJZAMWjQAJp269+QtLv1GT5y1fEPpcxV2cGxqYW1mrAqiDwAK7gpKBk4GjIZPIJ0FAAsog4eLBmKOSUADwA0mjQAB4w4FYCaADW0Fhk8Ji4BEQkhVgAfAAUjVhcJQCUXH32glzYeITEpBRYANolALpLAOSTAhurI2gAvD1ts50LlCvrG74KuzSa9MSQUbCJ0bGQ8YkTEo6I4Fh9rQGCC0AB6MFoABK0AKADpkMREDAAKIKaCydKQOE4h5qNCIOr-LDhEDJPSQNAACzY+XOVAOSRSODSmWyuTp3T6GxEZA2I2A5P0aHgHk5i0OTNS4CxWRycHFlG5AVcwQ8-JAkHaaAAggCZtASk1JYMWicOvNuoKEsKAO5U5HQABucCNQ11+vabslGxxcI2BKJAPBkMM0Ep8D4sl1om01opaHtjpdsC8U3Ncy6iyWeqwBrdV22d0ZACkAMoAeQAcnCcIhYAJoNyA2CAFRoMMRqMx7RoVtggVCylJmApxUMqUsmVs+V5AqLIq5-NNfoj52upqDm3Dh2juAG6btTP0nOevAFzY3YuJ3fruf0vprlNpgQCsBQOBIVBoXkv+4gxAuHAKJZAAIzgUlBQUQk6l5f8GBwKJQIUUBkB4X5lDEX5JWoVRAwJAFIIgGAEBQdAVSCdxrD-YEGFArh9FgCBDEg5BoIEOoKLcEIrHg+hEOQ1D0IcfwKVVKjPGwxlcPw4lIKAA)

Comment: Hmm, but I want to define mapper for multiple components at once, so that I can use it arbitrarily based on what components it's aware of. If type is X, it asks for props P[X] and renders Component[X]. If type is Y, it asks for props P[Y] and renders Component[Y].

Comment: Try having your `componentMapperFactory` accept the TypeDirectory as an argument.

`componentMapperFactory<D extends { [key: string]: { props: any, impl: any}>({
  'Hero': { props: HeroProps, impl: Hero },
  ...
} as const)`

Don't forget the `as const` in your definition, this is what makes the TypeDirectory work.